# CFHTTP and HTTPS Post Issue

Tags: coldfusion, https, cfhttp

I am posting jobs in the XML format to HTTPS url using `cfhttp` POST.
I get below error.

> I/O Exception: Name in certicicate 'jobserve ltd' does not match
>   hostname 'xml.jobserve.com'

So then according to instructions here http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2005/1/29/keystore I have done below things.

- In IE browser I went to https://xml.jobserve.com
- Exported the certificate from Details tab with Copy to file button.
- Went to command prompt and imported SSL certificate (.cer) file into `C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\jre\lib\security` using keytool.exe that ships with ColdFusion. It was successful imported.

Later went to post my request again...same issue. What else needs to be done?
We use CF 8 and this is a multi domain SSL certificate (https://xml.jobserve.com).

Can you please help?

Thanks,
Hitesh

Answer (score 3):

After inserting the certificate you must restart the ColdFusion server.

This Knowledge Base article has additional information.  It also provides a different location for your truststore (cf_root/runtime/lib). Ultimately it needs to be the location specified in your jrun.xml file.

> *Note:* If you are using JRun as the underlying J2EE server (either the Server Configuration or the Multiserver/J2EE with JRun
>   Configuration) and have enabled SSL for the internal JRun Web server
>   (JWS), you will need to import the certificate to **the truststore
>   defined in the jrun.xml file for the Secure JWS rather than the JRE
>   key store**. By default, the file is called "trustStore" and is
>   typically located under `jrun_root/lib` for the Multiserver/J2EE with
>   JRun configuration or `cf_root/runtime/lib` for the ColdFusion Server
>   configuration. You use the same Java keytool to manage the trustStore.

From: [Jrun Help / 
Import certificates | Certificate stores | ColdFusion](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/import-certificates-certificate-stores-coldfusion.html)

[Naveen Chhabra's Blog](http://naveenchhabra.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/trusting-certificate-in-coldfusion-using-keytool-utility/) also has similar information in a step by step process.